# What is the cleanest way to override a Wordpress plugins' hook instantiated with $this

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to modify a Wordpress plugins' method without changing the plugin core code itself. I need to set some status flag in a different part of the website.
The method is defined in the plugin class like so:

```
add_action('plugins_action_name', [$this, 'local_method_name']);
```

The plugin method does not offer any actions or filters to hook into.

If this wasn't Wordpress but plain PHP I would write my own class, which extends the plugins' original class but has it's own method by the same name - but in Wordpress this gets me nowhere since I just move the problem from one plugin file to the next.

Is there a way to remove the plugins action altogether? And then redefine my own version of it? 
Since the add_action has been called with `$this` - how would I remove it in some functions.php file?

Thanks

### UPDATE

Indeed I want to learn how to handle different scenarios. Not expecting a one size fits all solution, but I do need to know how to avoid core changes, as each core-change complicates my deploy/update process exponentially.

Sure I will add some more details. My example plugin is WooCommerce Germanized Pro which comes with a WC_GZDP_Download_Handler::download() method which I needed to modify, in order to set some sort of "Warehouse downloaded the invoice" flag for each order. Which is later used to highlight new orders, filter orders that have been handed over to fulfilment etc.
There seems to be a Invoice Helper class which does in fact have a singleton pattern.

my modification in the download class is trivial:

```
public static function download( $pdf, $force = false ) {
    ... /* original code above, now my modifications */
    if ($check_some_codition) {
        $invoice = $pdf->get_invoice();
        update_post_meta($invoice->get_id(), 'some-flag', 'some-value');
    }

    /* then resume original function (return the file to the browser) */
    self::out( $filename, $file, $force );
}
```

Comment: `remove_action` is what you are looking for. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/

Comment: @ascsoftw yes, but they’d still need the equivalent of `$this` at that point to be able to remove this specific action again.

Comment: The second parameter is basically a [PHP callable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) - but I think you’d need the specific object instance `$this` was pointing to to be able to remove it again, I don’t think supplying a different instance of the plugin class would work.

Comment: `$this` in this case will refer to your own Class where you are invoking `remove_action`.

Comment: There's no generic enough answer to the question. You *need* access to the original variable, or the same instance of the object in order to remove the action/filter. In some plugins they use a Singleton pattern which means you can access the instance of the plugin with something like `Plugin::getInstance()` or some use a global variable to store the plugin instance which you can also use to deregister the action/filter. You'd have to dig in to the plugin code to figure out if there's a way for you to get the instance - it's different for each plugin.

Comment: If you give us information about the plugin (assuming it's publically available) we can help to resolve it for you, but there's no "_one size fits all_" solution.

Comment: Indeed I want to learn how to handle different scenarios. Not expecting a one size fits all solution, but I do need to know how to avoid core changes, as each core-change complicates my deploy/update process exponentially Sure I will add some more details.